# Plot average line in a facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data set:

```
structure(list(Geschaeft = c(0.0961028525512254, 0.0753516756309475, 
0, 0.0722803347280335, 0, 0.000877706260971328), Gaststaette = c(0.0981116914423463, 
0.0789718659495242, 0.0336538461538462, 0.0905857740585774, 0, 
0.00175541252194266), Bank = c(0.100843712334271, 0.0717832023169218, 
0.00480769230769231, 0.025, 0.00571428571428572, 0.00965476887068461
), Hausarzt = c(0.0633989554037766, 0.0589573851882499, 0.0288461538461538, 
0.0217573221757322, 0.00685714285714286, 0.0128730251609128), 
    Einr..F..Aeltere = c(0.0337484933708317, 0.0550268928423666, 
    0.00480769230769231, 0, 0.00114285714285714, 0.000292568753657109
    ), Park = c(0.0738449176376055, 0.0726623913942904, 0.0625, 
    0.0846234309623431, 0.00228571428571429, 0.112053832650673
    ), Sportstaette = c(0.0449979911611089, 0.0612846503930492, 
    0.00480769230769231, 0.0619246861924686, 0.00114285714285714, 
    0), OEPNV = c(0.10847730012053, 0.089056681836988, 0.264423076923077, 
    0.135669456066946, 0, 0.185488589818607), Mangel.an.Gruenflaechen = c(0.0867818400964243, 
    0.071369466280513, 0.144230769230769, 0.117259414225941, 
    0.260571428571429, 0.186951433586893), Kriminalitaet = c(0.108316593009241, 
    0.083678113363674, 0.389423076923077, 0.139330543933054, 
    0.334857142857143, 0.216500877706261), Auslaender = c(0.00715146645239052, 
    0.0212039718659495, 0.0480769230769231, 0.0550209205020921, 
    0.0114285714285714, 0), Umweltbelastung = c(0.108879067898755, 
    0.0846607364501448, 0, 0.143828451882845, 0.376, 0.228203627852545
    ), Einr..f..Kinder = c(0.0693451185214946, 0.0825403392635499, 
    0.0144230769230769, 0.0527196652719665, 0, 0.0444704505558806
    ), Einr..f..Jugendliche = c(0, 0.0934526272238312, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.000877706260971328), count = c(1466, 1821, 81, 1491, 
    330, 793), cluster = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), .Names = c("Geschaeft", 
"Gaststaette", "Bank", "Hausarzt", "Einr..F..Aeltere", "Park", 
"Sportstaette", "OEPNV", "Mangel.an.Gruenflaechen", "Kriminalitaet", 
"Auslaender", "Umweltbelastung", "Einr..f..Kinder", "Einr..f..Jugendliche", 
"count", "cluster"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

which I sort with

```
mdf <- melt(nbhpp[,-15], id.vars = 'cluster')
mdf <- transform(mdf, variable = reorder(variable, value, mean), y = cluster)
```

and plot with

```
ggplot(mdf, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=cluster, colour=factor(cluster))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous('Anteile', formatter = "percent") +
  scale_colour_hue(name='Cluster') +
  xlab('Infrastrukturmerkmal') +
  theme_bw() +
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=90, hjust=1), legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~cluster, ncol=3)
```

[image]

If I understand it correctly, the transform function sort the data by the average values. But how can I include these average values as a grey line to each plot?

Thanks for your help

---

UPDATE:

Just for clarification:

If I take a look at the output of the reorder statement

```
with(mdf, reorder(variable, value, mean))
```

than I get the following attributes:

```
attr(,"scores")
   Einr..f..Jugendliche        Einr..F..Aeltere              Auslaender            Sportstaette 
             0.01572172              0.01583642              0.02381364              0.02902631 
               Hausarzt                    Bank               Geschaeft         Einr..f..Kinder 
             0.03211500              0.03630061              0.04076876              0.04391644 
            Gaststaette                    Park                   OEPNV Mangel.an.Gruenflaechen 
             0.05051310              0.06799505              0.13051918              0.14452739 
        Umweltbelastung           Kriminalitaet 
             0.15692865              0.21201772
```

Which are sorted in the plot from left (lowest) to right (highest).
The question is, how to draw a line, with theses attributes...

Comment: To clarify: you want a horizontal line in each facet that indicates the mean for that facet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Edited answer

To add a line with the cluster averages, you need to construct a `data.frame` that contains the data.  You can extract the values from `mdf`:

```
meanscores <- attributes(mdf$variable)$scores
meandf <- data.frame(
  variable = rep(names(meanscores), 6),
  value    = rep(unname(meanscores), 6),
  cluster  = rep(1:6, each=14)
  )
```

Then plot using `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(mdf, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=cluster, colour=factor(cluster))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous('Anteile', formatter = "percent") +
  scale_colour_hue(name='Cluster') +
  xlab('Infrastrukturmerkmal') +
  theme_bw() +
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=90, hjust=1), legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~cluster, ncol=3) +
  geom_line(data=meandf, aes(x=variable, y=value), colour="grey50")
```

[image]

---

### Original answer

My original interpretation was that you wanted a horizontal line with overall means.

Simply add a `geom_hline` layer to your plot, and map the `yintercept` to `mean(value)`:

```
ggplot(mdf, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=cluster, colour=factor(cluster))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous('Anteile', formatter = "percent") +
  scale_colour_hue(name='Cluster') +
  xlab('Infrastrukturmerkmal') +
  theme_bw() +
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=90, hjust=1), legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~cluster, ncol=3) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=mean(value)), colour="grey50")
```

[image]

Comment: That is not what I meant... But I clarified above

Answer (score 3):

Create a data frame containing the mean values for each group.  There are many, many ways to do this in R, e.g.,

```
means <- ddply(mdf, .(y), summarise, mean = mean(value))
```

(In this case it seems that the value is the same in each facet.)

Now draw add a horizontal line to your plot.  Assuming it was previously called `p`,

```
p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean), data = means)
```

Comment: That is not what I meant... But I clarified above